# How to extract multiple parts of a string using awk/sed/perl?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I search for log files having errors using `egrep` and it outputs a bunch of files. What I want to do is manipulate those strings and present in a different way.

```
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/fac_unet_abp99507.log.20220708111219.26476752.0
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/fac_oxf_abp3506.log.20220708111219.26476752.0
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/cirrus_abp4296EI_20220824.log
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mcr/logs/prof_cmcr_abp4296MR.log.20220824150526.15728964.0
```

The output should look like:

```
ABP99507,UNET
ABP3506,OXF
ABP4296EI,CIRRUS
ABP4296MR,CMCR
```

I tried `awk` and `sed` and couldn't figure out a way to do this. I want to be able to make it dynamic and do it via regular expressions.

What I have tried so far is:

```
egrep -li "^error" /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*202207* | awk '/unet|cirrus|oxf|csp|cmcd|cmcr|nice/ {print}'
egrep -li "^error" /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*202207* | sed -n "s/.*\(cirrus|unet|cmcr|csp|cmcd|oxf|nice\)\(abp[0-9]*[A-ZA-Za-za-z]*\).*/\1,\2/p"
```

Sed doesn't work as the `"|"` operator is taken as literal; I am not using GNU version. Even escaping it doesn't work. Also I can't seem to make use of capture groups.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO else you may get close votes on your question(for requiring focus etc), thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts, I have voted to re-open now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for feedback. I have added additional information. Please let me know what else is to be corrected.

Comment: Do you want to get values(in output) from file's names? OR these are entries from your file from where you want to get expected output, sorry after edit its bit confusing now.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Simplest option would be, using `awk`'s field separator option. With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F'/|\\.|_' '{print toupper($8","$7)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to try with regular expression in `awk` then try. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/logs\/[^_]*_([^_]*)_([^.]*)\.log/,arr){print toupper(arr[2]","arr[1])}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** With GNU `sed`'s enabling ERE with `-E` option please try following code.

```
sed -E 's/.*logs\/[^_]*_([^_]*)_([^.]*)\.log\..*/\U\2,\U\1/' Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** Adding a NON-GNU `awk` solution using `match` function.

```
awk '
match($0,/logs\/[^_]*_([^_]*)_([^.]*)\.log/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)
  sub(/\.log/,"",val)
  split(val,arr,"_")
  print toupper(arr[3]","arr[2])
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. The first solution would work for me but in some cases the log files are named differently. For eg: `cirrus_abp3952EI_20220806.log`. Hence I was looking for a more dynamic approach. Unfortunately the last two won't work for me as I don't have the GNU installations of both awk and sed on the server. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @VanditGoel, have you checked first solution if it worked? It should work IMHO. also check your awk version `awk -V` normally we can just check awk version by this command

Comment: @VanditGoel, also other two approaches are generic only(since regex needs some specific pattern so I further explained in this comment what is pattern), but they consider that you have logs directory before path name you want to extract and you file name is ending with .log which looks fair to me by seeing your another sample in your comment.

Comment: @VanditGoel, I have added 4th solution a NON-GNU `awk` which should work in most of the `awk` versions, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @VanditGoel, Please edit your question and show more examples of different filenames. We like to find a pattern that matches all filenames.

Answer (score 2):

> Also I can't seem to make use of capture groups.

You did not escape `|` so they are meaning literal `|`, you need to escape it to mean alternative, as is case with `(` and `)` (literal vs group delimiter). After doing that and repairing minor issues I get it working: let `file.txt` content be

```
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/fac_unet_abp99507.log.20220708111219.26476752.0
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/fac_oxf_abp3506.log.20220708111219.26476752.0
```

then

```
sed -e 's/.*\(cirrus\|unet\|cmcr\|csp\|cmcd\|oxf\|nice\)_\(abp[0-9]*[A-ZA-Za-za-z]*\).*/\2,\1/' -e 's/[a-z]/\U&/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ABP99507,UNET
ABP3506,OXF
```

Explanation: I introduced following changes: escaped `|`, added `_` between groups, change order of replacement (2nd group is first), dropped `/p` as it caused doubling output. After doing this I added second action: uppercasing using standard GNU `sed` way of doing so. As there are now 2 actions, I use `-e` to register them.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Answer (score 1):

Throw away `egprep` (which is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` by the way), and just use awk, e.g. using an awk that supports `nextfile` such as GNU awk (also already supported in some other awks and soon will be required per POSIX):

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    tolower($0) ~ /^error/ {
        split(toupper(FILENAME),a,/[_.]/)
        print a[3], a[2]
        nextfile
    }
' /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*202207*
```

or using any awk:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    FNR==1 { searching=1 }
    searching && (tolower($0) ~ /^error/) {
        split(toupper(FILENAME),a,/[_.]/)
        print a[3], a[2]
        searching=0
    }
}' /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*202207*
```

If you really want to implement what you were apparently trying to do with `/unet|cirrus|oxf|csp|cmcd|cmcr|nice/` to restrict which files the script examines then change this:

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    ...
}' /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*202207*
```

to this:

```
shopt -s extglob
awk -v OFS=',' '
    ...
}' /abcd/efgh/ijkl/logs/*@(unet|cirrus|oxf|csp|cmcd|cmcr|nice)*202207*
```